# Not receiving any response from SMTP server after successfully connected via openssl or telnet

Tags: postfix, smtp, openssl, telnet

I am trying to set up my postfix using Gmail smtp relay server. I have set it up in other servers without issues, but I am having difficulty getting it to work in my work network.

I tested if there is a network blockage by using `telnet smtp.gmail.com` with ports 25, 587 and 465, and in all instances I successfully connect to the server (msg 220), but I get no more output, even when typing EHLO.

I also tried openssl as shown below, and I dont get any additional output other than "CONNECTED". What may be happening? Could this be the result of a network firewall rule?

```
$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -ign_eof -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:587

CONNECTED(00000003)
```

Comment: Did you figure out why?

Comment: no I did not. I assumed there is some blockage in my work network, not sure if it was a valid assumption.

Comment: I figured out that, in my case, I was using `-starttls smtp` on port 465 that is used for implicit TLS instead of on port 587 (default one for starttls)